# Авторизация в Android App через Rest API и использование WebView

Tags: android, spring, webview, spring-mvc, spring-security

Хочу реализовать Android клиент для своего сервиса. Сервис написан на java c использованием Spring Security. Авторизация и связь клиента с сервером через Rest API.
Интересует следующий вопрос. Если в Activity использовать WebView и обратится по URL к серверу, меня будет перекидывать на страницу авторизации?

Comment: Для редиректа во WebView описано тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066438/android-webview-how-to-handle-redirects-in-app-instead-of-opening-a-browser

Comment: @ravikwow Вопрос был не в том, откроет ли страницу авторизации через App или браузер, скорее всего я не правильно задал вопрос. Меня интересует, если я авторизируюсь в App через REST API и внутри приложения буду обращатся к серверу через url из WebView, сервер меня разсмотрит как авторизированого пользователя или нет ?